# jquery slider error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addClass' of undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have problem with my jQuery slider. After I update the value of the slider it does not work anymore and shows an error that says

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addClass' of undefined".
```

I don't have any idea to figure this out. Thanks!

Here is the sample code:

```
 $("#slider-range").slider({

        range:true,     
        min: minPrice,
        max: maxPrice,  
        values:[ minPrice ,  maxPrice ],        
        slide: function( event,ui ){},

        change: function( event,ui ){

            $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[0] + " - $" + ui.values[1] );
        }           
    });
```

Comment: Maybe some code example?

Comment: You should show some code in a working example

Comment: You're trying to add a class to an invalid selector, where that selector is in your code is impossible to tell without actually seeing some code?

Comment: there's no call to `addClass` in the code you provided

Comment: `addClass` is in the jQUI source, dude

Answer (score 10, accepted):

---

type error: 
it seems you have an invalid value set to the value of your slider.
therefore it cant load - liek putting an int in a string and use it as a boolean - wont never work ...

:)-

cheers

BIEG

Comment: tnx guys I already figured it out by setting the values and turn it into integer by using parseInt.. thanks for the idea @BIEG

Comment: UPDATE: "#amount" - > does "#amount" actually have a value?
or rather: can you not go back in your code (cntrl-Z/AppleZ) to see where the change happened?

Comment: It's already fixed @BIEG. the problem was the value i pass on the slider was not read as an integer but as a string. So i added parseInt on the minPrice and maxPrice values and it works.